# Processing (OSM) PBF files in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, osm.pbf

OSM data is available in PBF format. There are specialised libraries (such as https://github.com/plasmap/geow for parsing this data).

I want to store this data on S3 and parse the data into an RDD as part of an EMR job.

What is a straightforward way to achieve this? Can I fetch the file to the master node and process it locally? If so, would I create an empty RDD and add to it as streaming events are parsed from the input file?

Answer (score 5):

One solution would be to skip the PBFs. One Spark-friendly representation is Parquet. In [this blog post](http://adrianulbona.github.io/2016/12/18/osm-parquetizer.html) it is shown how to convert the PBFs to Parquets and how to load the data in Spark.

Answer (score 2):

I released a new version of [Osm4Scala](https://github.com/simplexspatial/osm4scala) that includes support for [Spark 2 and 3](https://github.com/simplexspatial/osm4scala#spark-connector).

There are a lot of examples in the README.md

It is really simple to use:

```scala
scala> val osmDF = spark.sqlContext.read.format("osm.pbf").load("<osm files path here>")
osmDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, type: tinyint ... 5 more fields]

scala> osmDF.createOrReplaceTempView("osm")

scala> spark.sql("select type, count(*) as num_primitives from osm group by type").show()
+----+--------------+                                                           
|type|num_primitives|
+----+--------------+
|   1|        338795|
|   2|         10357|
|   0|       2328075|
+----+--------------+

scala> spark.sql("select distinct(explode(map_keys(tags))) as tag_key from osm order by tag_key asc").show()
+------------------+                                                            
|           tag_key|
+------------------+
|             Calle|
|        Conference|
|             Exper|
|             FIXME|
|         ISO3166-1|
|  ISO3166-1:alpha2|
|  ISO3166-1:alpha3|
| ISO3166-1:numeric|
|         ISO3166-2|
|           MAC_dec|
|            Nombre|
|            Numero|
|              Open|
|        Peluqueria|
|    Residencia UEM|
|          Telefono|
|         abandoned|
| abandoned:amenity|
| abandoned:barrier|
|abandoned:building|
+------------------+
only showing top 20 rows

scala> spark.sql("select id, latitude, longitude, tags from osm where type = 0").show()
+--------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|      id|          latitude|          longitude|                tags|
+--------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|  171933|          40.42006|-3.7016600000000004|                  []|
|  171946|          40.42125|-3.6844500000000004|[highway -> traff...|
|  171948|40.420230000000004|-3.6877900000000006|                  []|
|  171951|40.417350000000006|-3.6889800000000004|                  []|
|  171952|          40.41499|-3.6889800000000004|                  []|
|  171953|          40.41277|-3.6889000000000003|                  []|
|  171954|          40.40946|-3.6887900000000005|                  []|
|  171959|          40.40326|-3.7012200000000006|                  []|
|20952874|          40.42099|-3.6019200000000007|                  []|
|20952875|40.422610000000006|-3.5994900000000007|                  []|
|20952878| 40.42136000000001| -3.601470000000001|                  []|
|20952879| 40.42262000000001| -3.599770000000001|                  []|
|20952881| 40.42905000000001|-3.5970500000000007|                  []|
|20952883| 40.43131000000001|-3.5961000000000007|                  []|
|20952888| 40.42930000000001| -3.596590000000001|                  []|
|20952890| 40.43012000000001|-3.5961500000000006|                  []|
|20952891| 40.43043000000001|-3.5963600000000007|                  []|
|20952892| 40.43057000000001|-3.5969100000000007|                  []|
|20952893| 40.43039000000001|-3.5973200000000007|                  []|
|20952895| 40.42967000000001|-3.5972300000000006|                  []|
+--------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely take a look at the Atlas project (written in Java): https://github.com/osmlab/atlas and https://github.com/osmlab/atlas-generator. It is being built by Apple's developers and allows distributed processing of osm.pbf files using Spark.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a spark data source for .pbf files. It uses Osmosis libraries underneath and leverages pruning of entities: https://github.com/igorgatis/spark-osmpbf

You probably want to read .pbf and write into a parquet file to make future queries much faster. Sample usage:

```scala
import io.github.igorgatis.spark.osmpbf.OsmPbfOptions

val df = spark.read
    .format(OsmPbfOptions.FORMAT)
    .options(new OsmPbfOptions()
             .withExcludeMetadata(true)
             .withTagsAsMap(true)
             .toMap)
    .load("path/to/some.osm.pbf")

df.printSchema
```

Prints:

```
root
 |-- entity_type: string (nullable = false)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- tags: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- nodes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- index: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- nodeId: long (nullable = false)
 |-- members: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- member_id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- role: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```